# Mathematica hangs on manipulation

Tags: manipulate

Mathematica hangs on this code and after abort returns strange evaluation

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkGyV.png"];
imagecropped = image;
Manipulate[
 {Show[ImageAdjust[image, {c, b}],
   Graphics[{Transparent, EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[p, q]}]], 
  Show[imagecropped, ImageSize -> 200]},
 {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator, 
  Appearance -> Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, .1]}, ImageSize -> 10]},
 {{q, {1, 1}}, Locator, 
  Appearance -> Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, .1]}, ImageSize -> 10]},
 {{c, 0, "Contrast"}, 0, 1, 0.1},
 {{b, 0, "Brightness"}, 0, 1, 0.1},
 ControlPlacement -> Left
 ]
```

Here is the image
[image: image00001.bmp]

There is some error in the code or something strange is going on?
Thanks

Comment: Did you restart and try again?  What version are you using?  It works well for me using 10.3, 10.4, and 9.0

Comment: @JasonB: I'm running version 10.1 under ubuntu 14.04. I tried to restart but the problem is still there. I guess I need to update, then.